# How to define cache adapter in Symfony from env variable?

Tags: php, symfony

In my Symfony 7 app I have the following config in cache.yaml:

```yaml
framework:
    cache:
        default_doctrine_dbal_provider: 'doctrine.dbal.default_connection'
        pools:
            cache.score_prediction:
                adapter: '%env(CACHE_ADAPTER)%'
```

And in my .env.local I have:

```
CACHE_ADAPTER=cache.adapter.doctrine_dbal
```

However when running this, I get:

> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\EnvParameterException: Incompatible use of dynamic environment variables "CACHE_ADAPTER" found in parameters.

I want to be able to define cache adapter based on local dev machines (some have redis, some have dbal only etc.). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

So, you must understand what some parameterы we can pass via ENV to application, some parameterы cannot (via configuration).

Symfony compile internal container (dependency injection), and if symfony compile service based on configuration (parameter), this parameter can't be passed via ENV, and MUST presented originally in configuration.

Cache pools compile all services on build process, and you can't use ENV parameters here.

Ok, what about define service based on env (local, dev, prod, etc...)? For this, you can implement factory pattern and create you service based on any condition:

```
class CacheFactory
{
    public function create(string $env): CacheItemPoolInterface
    {
        if ('prod' === $env) {
            return new RedisAdapter();
        } elseif ('dev' === $env) {
            return new ArrayAdapter();
        }
        
        return new ArrayAdapter();
    }
}
```

And configure it:

```
services:
    cache.factory:
        class: CacheFactory
    
    cache:
        class: Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\ArrayAdapter
        factory: [ '@cache.factory', 'create' ]
        arguments: [ '%kernel.environment%' ]
```